# Is there a clean way of combining nginx location rules?

Tags: nginx

Suppose that in my nginx server I want to accomplish these two requirements:

1) all `*.php` files are to be passed to the php interpreter

2) directory `/private/` should require http authentication

If I write

```
location /private/  {
  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  ....
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     .... more settings
}
```

then (if I'm not mistaken) the authentication will only apply to non php files. If instead I add the `^~` flag to the `location` block, then I loose the php location. This is logical, because nginx only matches one location block.

It seems that the only option left is to use a nested location:

```
location /private/  {
  auth_basic            "Restricted";
  ....
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
         .... more settings
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     .... more settings
}
```

This looks rather clumsy and fragile to me: each time I add a protected dir location (or some dir with some special setting), I must remember to add nested locations for PHP (and perhaps other file types). But it seems to be the only way to go. Is this so?  Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no cleaner way, as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/119076/how-to-use-fastcgi-globally-and-basic-auth-in-sublocations-in-nginx), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/375961/nginx-basic-http-authentication-on-php-script) and in the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

But, you should probably use a separate file for your php configuration, that way, all you have to do is this:

```
location /private/  {
    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    ....
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include phpconf.conf;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
   include phpconf.conf;
}
```