# Nginx fails to load static after putting caching configuration

Tags: nginx, cache

I am trying to implement leverage browser caching for nginx. But when i insert the code inside conf file static files are not served by nginx showing 403 permission denied error.

This is my conf file

```
server {

   listen  80;
   server_name site.in;
   root /root/site-demo/;
   access_log /var/log/site/access_log;
   error_log /var/log/site/error_log;

   location static/ {
      alias /root/site-demo/static/;
   }

   location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
      proxy_redirect     http://127.0.0.1:4000 http://site.in;
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
   location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
   }
}
```

When i remove the cache expire part everything works fine. How can i put the expires part inside location static using if condition ?

Comment: Nginx only uses one location block, whichever is the most specific match.

Comment: So how can i mix both ?

Comment: [Look for duplicates](http://serverfault.com/questions/607051/is-there-a-clean-way-of-combining-nginx-location-rules).