# nginx http auth only working on folders, not on files

Tags: nginx, http-authentication, htpasswd

I am new to nginx and I really enjoy how fast it is in combination with php-fpm.

I want to protect a folder with

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /;
            auth_basic "restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /www/config/global.passwd;
    }
```

this works by accessing `/`, but on hitting `/test.php` it does not ask for a password.
It does ask for one at `/test/` so this only works for folders.

How to include files for protection?

Comment: At a guess, you have a location block for handling PHP files and `/test.php` is matching that block and not the one you have posted above. Try `/test.htm` and see if you get the same result to verify.

Comment: That's it.. how can I combine or avoid to make several containers for each folder with php files :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of this:

[How to use FastCGI globally and Basic Auth in sublocations in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/119076/how-to-use-fastcgi-globally-and-basic-auth-in-sublocations-in-nginx)

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

I solved the problem by putting `location` containers into other `location` containers.

Thx cyberx86 for the initial hint.